# What's the best hack to ripen avocados quickly?

Tags: food

Anything that has avocados in the recipe is ten times better in my opinion, in tacos, in salad, on toast, on soup, etc... but it's a tricky fruit. Often the grocery store only has tough, green avocados that aren't ready to be cut and eaten, but you need them that night for your dinner recipe. How can you ripen avocados quickly?

Comment: See also https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/89/28879

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many fruits ripen faster when exposed to the ethylene gas given off by ripening fruit. Seems a bit circular, but that just implies [storing fruit together in a sealed container](https://www.eatingwell.com/article/2061904/how-to-ripen-an-avocado/) (e.g., closed plastic box or bag) to contain the gas they produce speeds ripening.

Apples, pears, peaches and other fruit can be used to ripen the avocado, too. Just store them together in a box at room temperature, or **slightly** warmer.

Answer (score 0):

Like bananas, avocados can be ripened by gently microwaving them.

(Note that they become softer, but not necessarily sweeter or with a fully developed taste.)

Answer (score 0):

**The 'Time Is Ripe' Avocado Lifehack**

When you want your avocado(s) to be ready…

1. Pre-heat your oven to 250°F (120°C).
2. Wrap it (or each) in aluminum foil.
3. Put the avocado(s) in the oven.
4. Pull them out of the oven in 10 minutes

Bon appétit.

Comment: Hot avocado is IMO disgusting. Do you have a preferred solution for quickly chilling them?

Comment: @StuartF Rush, rush, rush. Why is everyone so impatient? I guess that after removing it/them from the oven and unwrapping them you could… wait for a bit. Continue preparing your recipe and plate it — by then everything will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Two personally tested options:

- Put in boiling water for 2-3 minutes
- Put in a bag with apples

Comment: Putting with other fruit has already been given.